# How to extract the value of an excel cell using Python?

Tags: python, excel

I have an excel cell that contains a formula (eg '= A1 + B1').

I want to extract the value (es.'a = Scheda_zero.cell (line, 13) .value ')

The shell returns me the string of the formula contained ('= A1 + B1').

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you using a python excel package? If so which one? openpyxl has a `data_only=true` attribute when loading a workbook

Comment: Thank you. Everything works now. But where are you find this solution? I try to serch it in readthedocs (openpyxl) but I did not find it...

Comment: I just did a quick google search and found it on anther SO question. Also, its what I have in my code

Comment: Well! I have another small problem.
I edit an excel file with a protected sheet.
Everything works perfectly.
When I save the file some cells are locked e
the subsequent user can not write inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `openpyxl` `data_only` kwarg as @pmkro indicated, but note that this will give you `None` if the function has never been evaluated. Open the excel file and let the functions evaluate before saving if this happens.

Then you can read the file as usual:

```
openpyxl.load_workbook("file.xlsx", data_only=True)
```

And select the cell as usual:

```
cell = sheet["A1"].value
```